# How can I Include empty cells in my chart?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, charts, flatten, is-empty

What should I do to include the empty cells in my chart?
I can't find any help in the parameters...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such option. you would need to feed it from helper formula:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(IF(A2:B11="", "vider", A2:B11)))
```

[image]